# How to set frames for multiple devices in ios?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios7

Hi everyone I am new ios development. I m creating an app that will run in ios5 as well as ios7. My problem is that when i set an image frame for ios5 in display perfectly in simulator but when i run it on a device then Y-co-ordinate automatically increases and the position of an image changes.please anyone tell me why this happening and how to set frames for different devices in single app.

Comment: It's not iOS which is reason for the change, it's the iPhone<5 and iPhone5 which makes the difference. If you want your view at same position just remove the autolayout

Comment: Why are you supporting iOS 5, or even iOS 6? Considering that iOS 7 is on ~80% of all devices, unless you're specifically targeting older devices you could save yourself a lot of hassle by going iOS 7 only.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't check the device or iOS model for this. You should be using Auto Layout or UIView Autoresizing masks. There are various WWDC videos about those topics.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
    //IOS 6
}
else if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) > NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1){
    //IOS 7
}
```

You can try this, this code will give you the version of ios. Let me know if that helps.. :)

**Edit:**

If you want to get the size of your screen try the below code:

```
CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenRect.size.height == 568) {
    //Its IPhone 5
}
else if (screenRect.size.height == 480){
    //Its below iPhone 5
}
```

Comment: You should not use `systemVersion` to check the which version of iOS your are running. But you should check the foundation version: `if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1)`

Comment: @rckoenes Does systemVersion has any bad effect?? I don't know. Let me know about it, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Well the `systemVersion` is just a string which you are casting to a float. Then comparing. The `foundationVersionNumber` is the number of the underlayout SDK so to say and is used to identify changes in it working. Apple suggest you use `foundationVersionNumber` to detect iOS versions. For example the Apple TV is systemVersion differs from the iOS version number but not form the foundation number.